# What's the difference between "api.rubyonrails.org" and "rails.rubyonrails.org"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

If I use http://api.rubyonrails.org/ to look up ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#url_for (see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) it tells me:

"This takes the same options as url_for in Action Controller (see the documentation for ActionController::Base#url_for)."

So I want to look up ActionController::Base#url_for, and I enter "ActionController" in the little search box on http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and that gives one result: "ActionController"... I click on that, and find "CLASS ActionController::Base"... I click on that... and there is no sign of url_for.

So then I Google "ActionController::Base#url_for" ( http://www.google.com/search?q=ActionController::Base%23url_for )... and skip the first result for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html since url_for is not mentioned there. However the second result http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html does show url_for... here's the direct link: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000455

Could someone please explain what is the difference between those to documentation sources?

And I guess another related question is: Where can I find docs for ActionController::Base#url_for at http://api.rubyonrails.org/ ?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: If you are working with Rails, I find it much easier to use the local documentation generated by RDoc and / or Yard. With a Yard server running (see http://yardoc.org/), you can even search the documentation. And you are sure to use the right one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rails.rubyonrails.org looks like it hasn't been updated since Rails 2.3.8, which http://api.rubyonrails.org is based on the current 3.1.1 version.

I think the "see the documentation for ActionController::Base#url_for" item is just something that never got cleaned up, as the options are now listed directly in the `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#url_for` documentation.

Comment: api.rubyonrails.com is now the only one that responds. rails.rubyonrails.org is deprecated.